# laravel relation belongsTo and method with

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have problem laravel relation. I use method with() in my controller and belongsTo in my model. My relation is normaly but if i get parent data this the problems.

**my models**

```
public function pekerjaan()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Pekerjaan', 'pekerjaan', 'id');
}
```

**This my controller**

```
 $data = Anggota::with('pekerjaan')->where('nik',$nik)->first();
 return $data;
```

**I want to get column 'nama_pekerjaan' in my relation 'pekerjaan'**
[image: I want to get column 'nama_pekerjaan' in my relation 'pekerjaan']

**if i use** `return $data->pekerjaan->nama_pekerjaan;`
show errors
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a column named `pekerjaan` and a relationship named `pekerjaan`. Laravel treats column names more than relationships. So yo can get the column value(id of `pekerjaan`) with the property `pekerjaan`. Give another name to your relationship to fix this alias problem.

In your model.

```
function pekerjaan_parent(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Pekerjaan', 'pekerjaan', 'id');
}
```

In you function

```
return $data->pekerjaan_parent->nama_pekerjaan;
```

Comment: How careless I am, thank you very much @Ramesh Kithsiri HettiArachchi

Comment: and laravel prefer 'Camel Case' for relationship names. use `pekerjaanParent()` or something

Comment: Thankyou very much @Tharaka Dilshan